# how to know the process who has sent the signal to the process traced?

Tags: linux, signals

I was using strace to debug an issue. and the process I traced will exit like:
kill(-27335, SIGTERM)                   = 0
--- SIGTERM (Terminated) @ 0 (0) ---

27335 is the PID of the process I traced.

is there anyway to know who has sent the SIGTERM to the process?

Comment: Since `-27335` is negative, it is some process in the same process group as 27335; it could be a shell, or some daemon (like `crond`, `sshd`, or `atd` ...). Use `pstree -p` to understand what are the processes in this process group...

Comment: You even want `pstree -p -g`  to display the process group ids

Comment: why the killer should be the same process group as the process? kill() can only be called by a process to kill the processes in the same process group?

Comment: because `kill(-27335, SIGTERM)` has been `strace`-d with a negative number.

Comment: alright, if I can know the processes with the same group id, then how to know who is the killer?